# Copy Windows to another CF card

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, bootloader

I need some help. Here is the scenario:

I have Windows XP Embedded on a 1 GB Flash Card. I have an empty 4 GB Flash Card.

I created the Primary Partition as explained [here](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-clean-and-format-storage-drive-using-diskpart-windows-10).

Now I was kind of stuck with the booting part. I used bootsec, I copied it from the Windows XP installer CD to my HDD. I executed it:

```
bootsect /nt52 CFCARD:
```

which seemed to work okay. I then copied all the files from the Windows XP to the other CF Card and tried to boot it and I just get a flashing cursor. I noticed that there are some hidden files in the rootdir like `boot.ini`, etc. Do I need to copy it as well?

Maybe some one can help me out and maybe point out my mistake or give me some advice. Maybe recommend some tools for that task. It is all about the changing size of the CF we try to use bigger CF Cards for Windows but having a hard time to get them to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you need to copy  a card like that, the best program to use is [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

Use this program to "read" the card into a .IMG file

Then use it to write that same image file out to another card.

The new card will need to be large enough to receive the image.

Resizing is possible but not reliable.